# Portable networking library written in C that is synchronous

Tags: library, networking, c

I am looking for a library for a portable (abstract differences between various Operating Systems) networking (for doing network stuff like BSD sockets) that is synchronous.

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library

In particular:

- It must be written in C
- It must be synchronous (exit epoll, kqueue, select...)
- It must be expose some kind of socket, unlike nng, nanomsg, zeromq.

The most similar thing is https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/networking.html but it will be preferable to not depend on gnome / gnu libraries.